# JS Не могу разобраться с синхронностью

Tags: javascript

Допустим у меня есть массив который я перебираю:

```
array  = [
    'item1',
    'item2',
    ....
]

array.forEach((item,i) => { ... //getAnyThing() }
```

Например при переборе я вызываю метод в котором есть setTimeout():

```
getAnyThing() {
    let w = window.open('anyUrl') // Просто пример в моём непонимании...
    setTimeout(() => {
        w.close();
    },10000);
}
```

Сам вопрос: как во время перебора дождаться выполнения моего метода и только после этого следовать дальнейшему перебору?

```
array.forEach((item,i) => { 
     setTimeout(() => {
         this.getAnyThing();
     },10000); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете использовать `async\await` для этого.

```js
array = [
  'item1',
  'item2',
  'item3',
]

async function getAnyThing() {
  await new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve();
    }, 1000);
  });
}

~async function() {
  for (let item of array) {
    await getAnyThing();
    console.log(item);
  }
}()
```

Comment: А у Вас этот код работает?

Comment: @OlmerDale, в chrome работает.

Comment: @Grundy я точно такой же ответ написал в jsbin но он у меня не заработал и пока я разбирался, дали этот ответ. Но меня удивило что и этот пример у меня не заработал. Хотя у меня тоже последний хром. И я даже начал сомневать в себе, пока на ноде не проверил :)

Comment: @OlmerDale, здесь он точно работает, я включил сниппетовскую консоль - она выводит все как надо. Возможно код был не совсем такой, а чем-то отличался, можно задать новый вопрос: почему такой код не работает :)

Comment: В Firefox тоже работает, если что

Comment: @OlmerDale да, интересно будет посмотреть, как такой код может не работать и почему. Очень полезно!

Comment: Фиг его знает чтоэто было.. Я перед тем как у Вас спросил работает код или нет, специально нажал править Ваш ответ для того чтобы поставить в настройках песочницы компиляцию с помощью бабеля. Но даже после этого код не заработал. Но сейчас работает. У меня скорее всего хром на ubuntu тупит. При чем впервые вчара заметил.